# how to use MailChimp for dynamic content and lists?

Tags: api, email, smtp, mailchimp

After reading through [MailChimp documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) I can't find how to send an email to a generated list of people from my database on my server and how to send it (with, let's say, a php script, or whatever scirpt).

Last, I would like to be able to generate emails dynamically, like have a template and fill out some variables with my own values. Just like you would do with mustache JS or any other templating system where you can have variables taking any value.

If we can't do that with MailChimp, do you know any other service that does what I'm looking for ? I don't want to send emails myself as I want to be able to track them the way mailchimp does.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by first creating a temporary campaign from a template.

Than I received the html code in the response.

I replace the variables on my server on the php side, while having my variables predefined and encoded individually like this ###MY_VARIABLE###

Than I create a new campaign from the modified html code.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://mandrill.com/

Dynamic you can send content in Mandrill template

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694286-How-do-I-add-dynamic-content-using-editable-regions-in-my-template-

Comment: Should Mandrill also be used to send newsletters, I do not think so?
I think the feature is also useful for MailChimp.... ?

Comment: Mandrill is adone plugin of Mailchimp if you want to send dynamic newsletter to the users for e.g you have news website and you want to send news latter when latest news published each day for that you can configure mandrill for news latter once new news added Mail alert sent to register user via mandrill.

Comment: I think Mandrill is for sending individualized e-mails to single users. E.g. "Thank you for registering", while MailChimp is for newsletter campaigns?

Comment: Yes mandrill send mail to single user to single mail which can be multipal as per your data see here http://kb.mailchimp.com/mandrill/mailchimp-vs-mandrill